# Installshield 2012 LE - Set folder location from registry entry

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield-le

After being forced to migrate from VS2010 to VS2012 to get an ActiveX control to work ... I now find myself in a situation where my existing installer project is no longer usable thanks to MS discontinuing support for them.

I have everything working in the bundled Installshield 2012 LE, except for one critical component:I need to place certain files in locations that are specified by registry keys on the target machine.

This was easy to do in an installer project, but I can see no way of doing it in Installshield LE.

If anyone can point me to a solution to this I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an answer, but it IS a solution.

I ditched Installshield and went with WIX!